# Can't serve static files from cherrypy

Tags: cherrypy

I'm starting to learn cherrypy but I've run in to a roadblock. I can't get static files to save my life. I'm getting a 404. `The path '/static' was not found.` I've googled however have yet to find a solution. All I want to do is serve files at http://localhost:8080/static

Suggetions?

```
import os
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        pass

config = {
    '/static':{
    'tools.staticdir.on': True,
    'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
    }
}

cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/', config = config)
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. In CherryPy 3.2+, try `tools.staticdir.debug = True`, combined with `log.screen = True` or some other more preferred logging setup. That will help more than anything I can guess at in this answer.
2. Try `tools.staticdir.dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'))`; it needs to be absolute (or, if .dir is not absolute, then tools.staticdir.root needs to be).
3. In CherryPy 3.1 and above, you usually need to call engine.block() after engine.start().

Comment: I added the debug and log lines and the path its checking is absolute. Here is the message: `Checking File: e:\\python\\cherrypyapp\\static\\` I double checked that path and its correct but I'm still getting a 404

Comment: Are you actually browsing to `http://localhost:8080/static`, as if you're trying to get a directory listing in your browser? The staticdir Tool doesn't provide index pages for the files it serves--you have to request an individual file, not a directory.

Comment: It was the engine.block() that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
web_config = {'/': {
    'tools.staticdir.on': True,
    'tools.staticdir.root' : os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))),
    'tools.staticdir.dir' : os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'))
},

    "/favicon.ico": {
        'tools.staticfile.on': True,
        'tools.staticfile.filename': "favicon.ico",
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': "images",
    },
    '/robots.txt': {
        'tools.staticfile.on': True,
        'tools.staticfile.filename': "robots.txt",
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': "", },

    '/images': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': "images",
    },

    '/css': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': "css",
    },

    '/js': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': "js",
    }
}
```

And started with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    cherrypy.config.update(server_config)
    cherrypy.tree.mount(WebSpid(), config=web_config)

    if hasattr(cherrypy.engine, 'block'):
        # 3.1 syntax
        cherrypy.engine.start()
        cherrypy.engine.block()
```